# Rails not getting the data to PostgreSQL from Radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise

I am building an app where the user has to enter their email, password, and gender in order to create a profile. We only used email and password and decided to add the gender later on but the user is not getting their Gender to their profile.

I used Devise for login that's why I do not have a "new" in my users' controller but maybe that needs to change?

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many_attached :photos
  has_one_attached :avatar
  geocoded_by :location
  after_validation :geocode, if: :will_save_change_to_location?

  include PgSearch::Model
  pg_search_scope :search_by_gender_location_and_breed,
    against: [ :gender, :location, :breed ],
    using: {
      tsearch: { prefix: true }
    }
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<div id="sign-up">
  <div class="container w-25 p-3 text-center input-container">
    <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :email,
              required: true,
              autofocus: true,
              input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
        <%= f.input :password,
              required: true,
              hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length),
              input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation,
              required: true,
              input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
          <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :gender, [['male', 'male'] ,['female', 'female']],:first, :last %>
      </div>
      <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", class:"sign_up_button" %>
    <% end %>
    <p>Or</p>
    <%= render "devise/shared/links", class: "mb-3"  %>
  </div>
```

Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @users = User.search_by_gender_location_and_breed(params[:query])
      @searched = true
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
    if params[:breed].present?
      @users = @users.select { |n| n.breed == params[:breed] }
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def like
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @chatroom = Chatroom.create(engager_id: current_user.id, receiver_id: params[:id])

    redirect_to user_path
  end

  def dislike
    @chatroom = Chatroom.find_by(engager_id: current_user.id, receiver_id: params[:id])
    @chatroom.destroy
    redirect_to user_path
  end

  def favorites
    fave_chats = Chatroom.where(engager_id: current_user.id)
    @favorites = []
    fave_chats.each do |chat|
      other_id = chat.receiver_id
      @favorites << User.find(other_id)
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to edit_user_registration_path }
      if avatar_params.present?
        @user.update(avatar_params)
        format.text { render partial: 'devise/registrations/avatar_form', locals: { user: @user }, formats: [:html] }
      elsif owner_params.present?
        @user.update(owner_params)
        format.text { render partial: 'devise/registrations/owner_info_form', locals: { user: @user }, formats: [:html] }
      elsif photos_params.present?
        @user.update(photos_params)
        format.text { render partial: 'devise/registrations/carousel', locals: { user: @user }, formats: [:html] }
      else
        @user.update(user_params)
        format.text { render partial: 'devise/registrations/cat_info_form', locals: { user: @user }, formats: [:html] }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :gender, :age, :breed, :description)
  end

  def avatar_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
  end

  def owner_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:owner_name, :location, :owner_description)
  end

  def photos_params
    params.require(:user).permit(photos: [])
  end
end
```

info.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { data: { edit_cat_target: 'form' } } do |f| %>
  <p data-action="click->edit-cat#displayNameField">
    <b>Name: <%= f.text_field :name, 'data-edit-cat-target': 'name', class: 'not-focused', 'data-action': 'blur->edit-cat#update' %></b>
  </p>
  <p data-action="click->edit-cat#displayAgeField">
    <b>Age: <%= f.text_field :age, 'data-edit-cat-target': 'age', class: 'not-focused', 'data-action': 'blur->edit-cat#update' %></b>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Gender: <%= @user.gender %></b>
  </p>
  <p data-action="click->edit-cat#displayBreedField">
    <b>Breed: <%= select :user, :breed, ['Abyssinian', 'American Shorthair', 'British Shorthair', 'Bengal', 'Birman', 'Burmese', 'Cornish Rex', 'Devon Rex', 'Exotic Shorthair', 'Himalayan', 'Maine Coon', 'Norwegian Forest Cat', 'Ocicat', 'Oriental Shorthair', 'Persian', 'Ragdoll', 'Russian Blue', 'Scottish Fold', 'Siamese', 'Siberian', 'Sphynx', 'Tonkinese', 'other - but still fabulous'], { include_blank: true }, 'data-edit-cat-target': 'breed', 'data-action': 'blur->edit-cat#update' %></b>
  </p>
  <p data-action="click->edit-cat#displayDescriptionField">
    <b>Description: <%= f.text_area :description, size: '40x10', 'data-edit-cat-target': 'description', class: 'not-focused', 'data-action': 'blur->edit-cat#update' %></b>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

devise.en.yml

```
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your email address has been successfully confirmed."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes."
    failure:
      already_authenticated: "You are already signed in."
      inactive: "Your account is not activated yet."
      invalid: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
      locked: "Your account is locked."
      last_attempt: "You have one more attempt before your account is locked."
      not_found_in_database: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
      timeout: "Your session expired. Please sign in again to continue."
      unauthenticated: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
      unconfirmed: "You have to confirm your email address before continuing."
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
        subject: "Confirmation instructions"
      reset_password_instructions:
        subject: "Reset password instructions"
      unlock_instructions:
        subject: "Unlock instructions"
      email_changed:
        subject: "Email Changed"
      password_change:
        subject: "Password Changed"
    omniauth_callbacks:
      failure: "Could not authenticate you from %{kind} because \"%{reason}\"."
      success: "Successfully authenticated from %{kind} account."
    passwords:
      no_token: "You can't access this page without coming from a password reset email. If you do come from a password reset email, please make sure you used the full URL provided."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions on how to reset your password in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive a password recovery link at your email address in a few minutes."
      updated: "Your password has been changed successfully. You are now signed in."
      updated_not_active: "Your password has been changed successfully."
    registrations:
      destroyed: "Bye! Your account has been successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon."
      signed_up: "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
      signed_up_but_inactive: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is not yet activated."
      signed_up_but_locked: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is locked."
      signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please follow the link to activate your account."
      update_needs_confirmation: "You updated your account successfully, but we need to verify your new email address. Please check your email and follow the confirmation link to confirm your new email address."
      updated: "Your account has been updated successfully."
      updated_but_not_signed_in: "Your account has been updated successfully, but since your password was changed, you need to sign in again."
    sessions:
      signed_in: "Signed in successfully."
      signed_out: "Signed out successfully."
      already_signed_out: "Signed out successfully."
    unlocks:
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions for how to unlock your account in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your account exists, you will receive an email with instructions for how to unlock it in a few minutes."
      unlocked: "Your account has been unlocked successfully. Please sign in to continue."
  errors:
    messages:
      already_confirmed: "was already confirmed, please try signing in"
      confirmation_period_expired: "needs to be confirmed within %{period}, please request a new one"
      expired: "has expired, please request a new one"
      not_found: "not found"
      not_locked: "was not locked"
      not_saved:
        one: "1 error prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:"
        other: "%{count} errors prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:"
```

I also tried to add validations to my user for gender but because it was an input field and i could not find how to do so but I do not think this is validation related.

Thank you!
Onur

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding additional params to my devise. Basically followed steps here.

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#strong-parameters

Thanks all!
Onur